# Making one of the UITabBarItem items have no view in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBarController with two "normal" UITabBarItem's that I add with the following code:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
```

Now I would like my UITabBar to have one extra item that acts differently, I would like it to be a "button" that opens the about view on top of the current view and thus not have a view the same way as the others (because I want this about view to have a special effect when it is shown), but other that that I want it to have the same style as the other items.

Can this be done, and how?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add blank view for the "specialButton" in tab bar and then handle this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

In this method you should redirect to previously active tab, and do your magic. I hope this is helpful...